# Avoiding CSRF Error message while enabling API endpoints (next() does not bypass the error message) Node Express JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this middleware here.

```
        /*
        * Middleware for rendering 404 page on invalid csrf token
        */
        this.app.use((err: any, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
            if (err.code === this.constants.CSRF.errCode) {
                let bypass = false;
                if (req.headers.referer || req.originalUrl || req.url) {
                    let is_referer_url     = '';
                    let is_originalUrl_url = '';
                    let is_url             = '';
                    // @ts-ignore
                    is_referer_url         = req.headers.referer;
                    is_url                 = req.url;
                    is_originalUrl_url     = req.originalUrl;
                    return REST_ENDPOINTS.forEach((endpoint) => {
                        if (is_referer_url == endpoint
                            || is_originalUrl_url == endpoint
                            || is_url == endpoint) {
                            bypass = true;
                            return this.redirect(res, endpoint);
                        }
                    });
                }
                if (!bypass) {
                    this.invalidCsrfResponse(req, res);
                }
                // this.invalidCsrfResponse(req, res);
                next()
            }
            if (err.code !== this.constants.CSRF.errCode)  {
                next(err);
            }
        })
```

the Code above just checks if any of the api endpoints include the api urls in the array `REST_ENDPOINTS`

the file of the array:

```
export const REST_ENDPOINTS = [
    "/get_example/",
    "/patch_example/",
    "/delete_example/"
]
```

The Problem is that it actually works but not exactly how it should, because in the code above the csrf error keeps poping up and I cant get rid of it.

```
this.app.use((err: any, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
            if (err.code === this.constants.CSRF.errCode) {
                // this.invalidCsrfResponse(req, res);
                next()
            }
            if (err.code !== this.constants.CSRF.errCode)  {
                next(err);
            }
        })
```

this code above bypass the csrf error completely, like I have not implement csrf at all. and it works like a charm, just not for api endpoints (not from same origin client requests) ???

I tried to disable CSRF error message because I need to disable it for API endpoints and it worked just not for another origin only for same origin client requests.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to use the csrf constructor without registering it in the `app.use()` function, and then passing it by for the normal app routes as middleware and ** not passing it as middleware to all the api's endpoints**.

Thread is solved.

```
    /*
    * CSRF Enabled
    */
    var CSRF = Csrf({
        sessionKey:    this.constants.CSRF.sessionKey,
        cookie:        this.constants.CSRF.cookie,
        ignoreMethods: this.constants.CSRF.ignoreMethods,
    });
    
    //? Deploying API's endpoints and bypass csrf on requesting these endpoints ?\\
    this.app.use((req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
        if (REST_ENDPOINTS.includes(req.headers.referer ?? '')
         || REST_ENDPOINTS.includes(req.originalUrl ?? '')
         || REST_ENDPOINTS.includes(req.url ?? '')) {
            return next();
        }
        CSRF(req, res, next);
    });
```